# Unable to use PSSH on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, ssh, ubuntu-11.04

Hi I just installed PSSH on my Ubuntu machine and Iä'm trying to use it to execute commands across multiple machines but I keep getting errors. Here's some sample output to show what's going on.

```
root@int:~# pssh -h hosts.lst -l mridang -A yakkayakka --print --verbose hostname
Warning: do not enter your password if anyone else has superuser
privileges or access to your account.
Password:
[1] 22:04:21 [FAILURE] XXX.XXX.XXX.XX Exited with error code 255
```

My hosts file looks like this:

```
root@int:~# cat hosts.lst
XXX.XXX.XXX.XX
```

The host exists and I'm able to SSH to it I don't believe it's an SSH issue. My PSSH version is 2.2.2.

(I've edited out the IPs for this post.)

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem just re-installed python-setuptools package and then again pssh. 
Seems rare but after that it worked ok.